# Unhandled Exception: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'ApiResponse<Map<String, dynamic>>'

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

I'm getting the following error while fetching data from server but I know this error is not about how I'm fetching data. It is related to the null safety which was added in latest flutter update. I'm not so much familier with it.

**Here is the Errors**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUzl5.png)

I tried to check if there was something wrong on the line highlighted and for me it was ok.

**Here is the code of servers_http.dart:**

````
    ApiResponse<Map<String, dynamic>> resp = await get<Map<String, dynamic>>("detail/random");
    if (resp.success ?? false) {
      return StarConfig.fromJson(resp.data!);
    }
    return null;
  }```

**and this stars_provider.dart**

```///Initialize engine and load last server
  void initialize(BuildContext context) {
    engine = OpenStar(onStarStageChanged: onStarStageChanged, onStarStatusChanged: onStarStatusChanged)
      ..initialize(
        lastStatus: onStarStatusChanged,
        lastStage: (stage) => onStarStageChanged(stage, stage.name),
        groupIdentifier: groupIdentifier,
        localizedDescription: localizationDescription,
        providerBundleIdentifier: providerBundleIdentifier,
      );

    Preferences.instance().then((value) async {
      starConfig = value.getServer() ?? await ServersHttp(context).random();
      notifyListeners();
    });
  }```


what I need to change?
````

Comment: Can you post the api response?

Answer (score 0):

**Slution 1:**

my understanding that you are requesting data from the server using

```
ApiResponse<Map<String, dynamic>> resp = await get<Map<String, dynamic>>("detail/random");
```

if so all you need to do is to change it to :

```
ApiResponse<Map<String, dynamic>>? resp = await get<Map<String, dynamic>>("detail/random");
if (resp?.success ?? false) {
    return StarConfig.fromJson(resp.data!);
}
```

**Slution 2:**

i believe this function is the problem and `starConfig` doesn't accept `null` and base on your code :

```
Preferences.instance().then((value) async {
    starConfig = value.getServer() ?? await ServersHttp(context).random();
    notifyListeners();
});
```

this part is returning `null` when his only job is to return `ApiResponse<Map<String, dynamic>>`

```
await ServersHttp(context).random()
```

now this i believe this will work if you

```
Preferences.instance().then((value) async {
    ApiResponse<Map<String, dynamic>> test;
    starConfig = value.getServer() ?? test.fromJson({});
    notifyListeners();
});
```

**Note :** i don't know what `ServersHttp(context).random()` do.